# Need to activate a plugin for a wordpress site through the php files

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I was going to update the ecommerce plugin (Shopp) on my wordpress site and it asked me to deactivate it. once I did that I lost the entire site.
I am trying to activate the plugin through the php files, but not sure what I am doing and would like some help.
Does anyone know how I can activate the Shopp plugin (or any plugin for that matter) on my site through the php files?

---

This is the code I'm using to get the string:

```
    $unserialized = unserialize('a:14:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:37:"breadcrumbs-plus/breadcrumbs-plus.php";i:2;s:35:"googleanalytics/googleanalytics.php";i:3;s:45:"grunion-contact-form/grunion-contact-form.php";i:4;s:43:"image-caption-links/image-caption-links.php";i:5;s:29:"image-widget/image-widget.php";i:6;s:13:"rate/rate.php";i:7;s:33:"restore-jquery/restore-jquery.php";i:8;s:41:"shopp-cache-helper/shopp-cache-helper.php";i:9;s:47:"shopp-default-breadcrumb-extender-sdbe/sdbe.php";i:10;s:33:"shopp-improved/shopp-improved.php";i:11;s:19:"shuffle/shuffle.php";i:12;s:19:"vslider/vslider.php";i:13;s:41:"wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php";}');
array_push($unserialized, 'shopp/shopp.php');
$serialized = serialize($unserialize);
echo $serialized;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The active plugins are not stored in a PHP file. It's stored in the database. Open the `wp_options` table in the database. Look for a row in which the value of the `option_name` field is `active_plugins`. In this row, look for the value of `option_value`. You'll see a serialized string containing the information of the active plugins.

Now, it might be a little bit confusing to edit the string straight away especially if you're not familiar how serialized strings are formatted. So, I suggest you copy the string and use PHP `unserialize()` function on it, which will then return an array. After that, use `array_push()` to add another element in which the value is the path to the plugins file (e.g. "akismet/akismet.php", in your case it might be "shopp/shopp.php"). Once you've add another element, use `serialize()` and copy the returned string and replace the old serialized string in the database.

```
$unserialized = unserialize('...');
array_push($unserialized, 'shopp/shopp.php');
$serialized = serialize($unserialized);
echo $serialized; // Copy this output back into the database
```

Comment: ok so I have the seralized string, after that you lost me. can you give me an example of how the PHP unserialized function will look like to put on option_value with the array_push()? i have the string if you want it.

Comment: Do I do this all directly on phpMyAdmin where the option_value box with the string is? @KemalFadillah

Comment: @Sophie run the above code in PHP. Just create a random file and paste the above code into it. And make sure you replace `...` with the serialized string from the database. Then, run the file and paste the output into the database; replacing the old serialized string.

Comment: @KernalFadillah this is all that I get.. i:15; this is the url im using to run it: [serialize string](http://poochclub.com/shoppactivate.php)

Comment: @Sophie Could you post the original serialized string please?

Comment: @KernalFadillah hmm now all I get is N;

Comment: @Sophie sorry I made a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10187/discussion-between-sophie-and-kemal-fadillah)

Comment: @KernalFadillah ok the sting worked. I copied it and put it on my databes. But my site is still gone....

Comment: there was a typo the file name. its up and running! thanks for all your help!!!! @KernalFadillah

Answer (score 2):

There are details on [this site](http://grinninggecko.com/activating-deactivating-wordpress-plugins-programmatically/) about how to programmatically activate and deactivate a plugin. Here is a snippet:

```
function toggle_plugin() {

    // Full path to WordPress from the root
    $wordpress_path = '/full/path/to/wordpress/';

    // Absolute path to plugins dir
    $plugin_path = $wordpress_path.'wp-content/plugins/';

    // Absolute path to your specific plugin
    $my_plugin = $plugin_path.'my_plugin/my_plugin.php';

    // Check to see if plugin is already active
    if(is_plugin_active($my_plugin)) {

        // Deactivate plugin
        // Note that deactivate_plugins() will also take an
        // array of plugin paths as a parameter instead of
        // just a single string.
        deactivate_plugins($my_plugin);
    }
    else {

        // Activate plugin
        activate_plugin($my_plugin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this have to be in a new php file that I add to my site?

Comment: I updated my questions since this is not working for some reason I keep getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in /home/p00chw3b/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1652 @Robbie

Comment: @Sophie looks like i'm a little late back to this conversation. sounds like you got it sorted though. Incidentally, you would have needed to 1. change the path to your plugin and 2. add this code to any file (eg functions.php) and then add a call to the function so that it was executed. And it should have toggled the activation state of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

*For everyone who has a plugin acting weird*

The easiest way to regain access to your site when being locked out after deactivating, activating, installing, updating a plugin is:

- Go to your webhost adminpanel (Cpanel, DirectAdmin)
- Go to Files (Filemanager)
- Go to //wp-content/ and rename your "plugins" folder to something else for instance "plugins_off"
- Go to your WP-admin. You will have access again but no plugins visible.
- Go back to your webhost adminpanel and rename "plugins_off" back to "plugins".

Now your plugins will all be listed again in WP-admin, but all deactivated.
Take it from there.

There is no need to add PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Like RST wrote: No need for coding to restore site that crashed after you deactivate a plugin. There's a good reason the site crashed because other plugins depended on that deactivated plugin (like WooCommerce).

The easiest way to restore the site and gain access to WP admin is simply to rename the plugins folder, refresh the page, go back and rename the folder back to "plugins" then hit refresh again. All plugins will be back as before only they are all deactivated. Now all you need to do is to activate them again. Do it one by one to be sure nothing else crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code
(just uncomment "activate" line):

```
function MY_toggle_plugins() {
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    $temp_files1 = glob(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/*'); 
    $activated=array();
    $already_active=array();
    foreach($temp_files1 as $file1){
        if(is_dir($file1)) { 
            $temp_files2 = glob($file1 . '/*');
            foreach($temp_files2 as $file2){
                if(is_file($file2) && stripos(file_get_contents($file2),'Plugin Name:')!==false) { 
                    $plugin_name_full=basename(dirname($file2)).'/'.basename($file2);
                    if(is_plugin_active($plugin_name_full)) {
                        array_push($already_active, $plugin_name_full); 
                        //deactivate_plugins($plugin_name_full);
                    }
                    else{
                        array_push($activated, $plugin_name_full);
                        //activate_plugin($plugin_name_full);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    echo 'You have activated these plugins:<br/><br/>'.serialize($activated).'<br/><br/>These were already active:<br/><br/>'.serialize($already_active); exit;
} 
//execute
MY_toggle_plugins();
```